# Test Q on Dictionarys (python)

Tags: python, file, dictionary

```
def process_students(r):

    '''r is an open reader with no data about students: their name, cdf account, age, college and 
       home city. Each line has the following format:
       name, cdf, age, college, city.

       there are no commas other than the ones used as separators.

       Return a dictionary in which each key is a college and its value is the list of cdf accounts 
       for students at that college'''
```

I am confused about how to work with this question. I'm doing this practice test and this is one of the questions. I started off by creating a new dictionary. What do I do next?

```
    d = {}
    for line in r:
         line.strip()
```

When we take lines out from a text file, do we always have to strip it?

Part b of the question is also confusing. It tells us to write a program that opens a file called 'students.txt', in the format described above, calls our function to build the dictionary, and pickles the dictionary to a file called 'students.pck.' We may assume `cpickle` has been imported and that function `process_students` has been defined.

I have no idea what pickle is. But I can't even finish the first one, so I have no idea how to continue on with the second one anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This being study, I think you'll learn more solving it yourself than reading someone's solution.  Good starting points would be to look at the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv) for parsing the input file and the tutorial section in python help for how to manipulate [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
import csv

def process_students(r):
    for row in csv.reader(r, delimiter=','):
        print row  # <-- rather than print, you should build dictionary here
```

Personally I'd use csv module.  An alternative loop for process_students could be:

```
    for line in r:
        row = line.strip().split(',')
        print row
```

Comment: mmm, could you somehow kinda give me a little guide through what I should do tho.

Comment: actually, as there is specifically mentioned that >>there are no commas other than the ones used as separators.<<, I think line.split(",") is the expected solution, not csv. Of course, in real-world programs, one would use the csv module.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Python CSV module for reading the data file, then as you process each csv line, insert the values into your dictionary. http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

In particular, look at this: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader

That probably explains the `reader` represented by the `r` param.

Comment: this is too complicated. i dont understand it, im new to it so anything beyond that is prob too muchu for me.

Comment: Python docs are some of the best around, fire up IDLE or something like ipython or dreampie and dig into the tutorial.

Comment: actually, as there is specifically mentioned that >>there are no commas other than the ones used as separators.<<, I think line.split(",") is the expected solution, not csv. Of course, in real-world programs, one would use the csv module.

Answer (score 0):

> When we take lines out from a text file, do we always have to strip it?

That's easy way to get rid of [end-of-line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character. I suppose you don't need them :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously most people would be reluctant to give you a full solution because you don't learn so much from it, but the guide does make things fairly simple. Here's some pointers...

1) You've read in your line. The line is a string. Use the string's split method to divide into a list of component strings. E.g., `"this,is,a,test".split(",") # => ["this", "is", "a", "test"]`

2) To access elements of a list:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
mylist[2] # => 3

#or map the values to variable names
a,b,c,d = mylist
```

3) Dictionaries are fun to use:

```
mydict = {}
mydict['things'] = []
mydict['things'].append("foo")
mydict['other_things'] = ["bar"]

mydict['things'] # => ["foo"]
mydict['other_things'] # => ["bar"]
```

These are just some hints towards the sort of things that will help you.